# Problems Installing Custom Xubuntu ISO: "no space left on device"

Tags: boot, xubuntu, iso, unetbootin, uck

I wanted to make a custom iso, so I used [the Ubuntu Customization Kit(UCK)](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/uck/). 
The ISO was created and I used [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to install it on a 4.0GB SanDisk flash drive. However, when I tried to boot from the flash drive, I got a "no space left on device" error. I ran the "check disk for defects" option and nothing was found. 
The iso created was ~1GB and the flash drive had 2.6GB of free space after the installation. What can I do to make my ISO bootable?

What I have tried:

Re-installing the iso.

Trying to boot the flash drive from a different computer

Testing with qemu, but all I got was a black screen

NOTE: The computer was able to boot other flash drives and the the flash drive was able to be booted with a different ISO.

Thanks in advance.